# Function that returns a list of the count of positive numbers and sum of negative numbers

Tags: python

I have a problem when I ran my code against the unit test. Any advice would be appreciated. Please find the code below:

```
def manipulate_data(data):
    count = 0
    sum1 = 0
    new_list = []
    for x in data:
        if x > 0:
            count += 1

        if x < 0:
            sum1 += x

    new_list.append(count)
    new_list.append(sum1)

    return new_list
```

The unit test is below:

```
import unittest

class ManipulateDataTestCases(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_only_lists_allowed(self):
    result = manipulate_data({})
    self.assertEqual(result, 'Only lists allowed', msg='Invalid argument')

  def test_it_returns_correct_output_with_positives(self):
    result = manipulate_data([1, 2, 3, 4])
    self.assertEqual(result, [4, 0], msg='Invalid output')

  def test_returns_correct_ouptut_with_negatives(self):
    result = manipulate_data([1, -9, 2, 3, 4, -5]);
    self.assertEqual(result, [4, -14], msg='Invalid output')
```

The error I get is:

```
`Total Specs: 3 Total Failures: 1
  1 .  test_only_lists_allowed
  Failure in line 11, in test_only_lists_allowed
      self.assertEqual(result, 'Only lists allowed', msg='Invalid argument')
    AssertionError: Invalid argument`
```

Comment: Your function actually does work with dict, and returns the "correct" result (in the case of `{}`, the result is `[0,0]`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the case of {}, the result of manipulate_data is [0,0]
try this:

```
def manipulate_data(data):
    if not isinstance(data, list):
        return 'Only lists allowed'

    count = 0
    sum1 = 0
    new_list = []
    for x in data:
        if x > 0:
            count += 1

        if x < 0:
            sum1 += x

    new_list.append(count)
    new_list.append(sum1)
    return new_list

import unittest

class ManipulateDataTestCases(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_only_lists_allowed(self):
    result = manipulate_data({})
    # print('result: ', result)
    self.assertEqual(result, 'Only lists allowed', msg='Invalid argument')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but i can't edit the test.

Comment: if you check if data is a list instance?, I add 
if not isinstance(data, list):
    return 'Only lists allowed'

Comment: You need return 'Only list allowed' for use assertEqual

Answer (score 1):

def manipulate_data(data):
    if not isinstance(data, list):
        return 'Only lists allowed'

```
count = 0
sum1 = 0
new_list = []
for x in data:
    if x > 0:
        count += 1

    if x < 0:
        sum1 += x

new_list.append(count)
new_list.append(sum1)
return new_list
```

Answer (score 0):

The results are correct. In `test_only_lists_allowed()` you are comparing the list returned by the function to the string `'Only lists allowed'`.

That test will fail.

Comment: i wasn't the one who wrote the tests and i cant edit them

Answer (score 0):

Did you write your unit test?  The person who did thinks that you should only be checking lists.  The way to do this in python is:

```
>>>l = []
>>>isinstance(l, list)
True
>>>d = {}
>>>isinstance(d, dict)
True
>>>isinstance(d, list)
False
```

The way it's written, your program will attempt to iterate over all iterables, including `dict`.  If you want to keep this behavior, keep in mind that it will iterate over keys, not values, of a `dict`.

Comment: i can't change the tests so i'm looking for a way to make my code work based on it

Comment: Your instructor (I assume) wants you to only check lists. isinstance(data, list) will return True if data is a list. The rest you should be able to do on your own

Comment: please can you explain cause what i returned was a list so i don't understand why it failed

Comment: The problem isn't that you returned a list, but that you tried to look through something that isn't a list.  The test in question runs manipulate_data({}).  {} is a dictionary, not a list.  Your instructor wants the manipulate_data function to return the string 'Only lists allowed' when it's called with something that's not a list.

Look at the message it gives you when it fails:  "Invalid argument".  The argument is the stuff you put in the parenthesis when you call a function.  So function(argument1, argument2).  You should check in your code if the argument is a list or not.